# Ways to force-stop or limit extent of After Effects tracking when you can't escape from it?

Tags: after-effects

I've been using tracking in After Effects a lot lately; tracking masks, tracking objects or the camera etc., and whenever I click that play ▶ button, there doesn't seem to be anything I can do to stop it, no matter what kind of tracking I implement.

The program completely ignores all of my clicks and I have no choice but to wait until it reaches the very end of a clip, which can be a VERY long time after the segment I care to track. I've had to leave AE for hours multiple times, to let it work on something even after I can clearly see that the mask is off and all the tracking has become useless.

All I can think to do now is to save right before I start ANY tracking, and force AE to quit if it gets caught in this loop, so I at least don't lose my work before clicking to track but that loses any time put in that DID get a useful track.

The tracker seems to ignore my active work-area selection that indicates what I actually intend to render.

Given my situation, what can you recommend I do to avoid losing AE to get locked in endless tracking?

I was thinking of:

- Using Shift-Control/Command-D to split the clip at a point where I don't need tracking any more, or where I know it will stop so I can at least have a chance to confirm the tracking is going well. But, I don't know how I'd re-merge them and this could make things messy. At the moment, this is the best I can think of, and to just have way too many "Pre-composed" layers of split clips to get around the problem.
- I could manually force the clip to just be shorter, but this messes up the workflow for later when I just need to extend it again and I'm worried about losing effects on later points in the clip.
- I can just click to track forward one frame and click again, then it won't get caught in its own automatic ad-nauseum tracking, but this is tedius.

Any other suggestions? My system is strong and can handle a lot that I throw at it, which is why I'm so confused as to why this happens so consistently. I'm on Windows 10, i7-5930K CPU, 32GB RAM, and the latest version of AE 2020.